# Access test SharePoint URL with Batch file or Powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sharepoint, active-directory, logfile

I'm trying to figure out how to test access to a SharePoint URL with something simple and without the need to install anything extra. Normal win10 environment, no admin rights. I had som code experience but not recently.

Short snip of what I have..:

```
:MENU
ECHO Text text text 
ECHO Menu with about 10 selections
SET /P M=Here you chose from different AD-testusers:

IF %M%==1 SET title=testuser1
IF %M%==1 GOTO A

:A
Runas /savecred /user:my_domain\some_user "C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe http://test_URL/"
ECHO %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% login %title% @ %DATE%,%TIME% >> log\log%DATE%.txt
GOTO MENU
```

That is ok and good enough in some cases but still have to check results manually. That log text output is not very important but I would like to include some info about if the user has access to that specific SharePoint page. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use powershell to check if the url returns code 200 (loading successfully)

[reference to this article](http://coreboarder.com/blog/?p=453)

Comment: Thank you! But I have problem understand the whole thing.. Ill keep try for sure. If you have something shorter 'only check one page and write host ok / not ok' I would be happy.

Comment: actually i think what you want is a script that check sharepoint permission (read / contribute / full control / denied ?) of a user ... am i right ?

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what Im looking for. Sorry for my sloppy written comment. Its 2013.

Comment: I think I got the thing under control. I needed to add som spaces to the code.. 

`foreach ($objItemin$urls) {` had to be `foreach ($objItem in $urls) {`
`Write-Host“Checking $objItem”;` had to be `Write-Host “Checking $objItem”;`

Comment: But now I have problem use this on other (test)users on the AD. What ever I do when trying to pass on other creds instead of `$req.UseDefaultCredentials=$true` I get **401 Unauthorized**.. Can you help me @Jeff?

Comment: unless you have the user credentials, this script will actually be useless. Now that i understand your requirement, let me revert back to you

Comment: are you able to run a program from the sharepoint server itself ?

Comment: 2nd question : do you have the end users credentials ?  how many users you need to test ? why cant they connect to the site and test ?

Comment: Its not impossible to make it run from server but I want to test the permissions as if they were to log on to their account from my computer. Or any computer inside the company network. 

I have credentials from about 15 test user accounts. Accounts without a real user. These 15 users represent about 250 real users with different permissions on a couple of different SharePoint servers.

Comment: Try this out ?   

Replace 
$req= [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($objItem)

By
$username = "accountname"
$pwd = "accountnamePassword"
$domain = "mydomain"
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential($username, $pwd, $domain);

Answer (score 0):

From the [link ive shared](http://coreboarder.com/blog/?p=453), edit the following

Try this out ?

**Replace**

```
$req= [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($objItem)
```

**By**

```
    $username = "accountname"
    $pwd = "accountnamePassword"
    $domain = "mydomain"
    $req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential($username, $pwd, $domain);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff! I had to do some changes but now its doing what I was looking for. Ended up with this added to parts of the code from the first link you posted and some from other sites. 

`$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($objItem) 
$req.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $pwd);`

Comment: great if that helped in your project ! please vote up my answer above ;)